# How to use cv2 image data as batch_x input in tensorflow

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, python-3.6

I want to use the imgs of my screen as tensorflow input data.
For recording the images I am using the script down below.

The image data is saved as **uint8** but tf needs **float32**.
So, how to convert it that i can input the image in **feed_dict**

```
loss, acc = sess.run([loss_op, accuracy], feed_dict={X: batch_x,Y: batch_y})
```

as **batch_x**?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as ts
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con, win32api
import cv2

def grab_frame(size=None):

hwin = win32gui.GetDesktopWindow()

if size:
    left, top, x, y  = size
    width= x - left + 1
    height= y - top +1

else:
    width = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN)
    height = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN)
    left = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN)
    top = win32api.GetSystemMetrics(win32con.SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN)



hwindc = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwin)
srcdc = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwindc)
memdc = srcdc.CreateCompatibleDC()
bmp = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
bmp.CreateCompatibleBitmap(srcdc, width, height)
memdc.SelectObject(bmp)
memdc.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), srcdc, (left, top), win32con.SRCCOPY)


signedIntsArray = bmp.GetBitmapBits(True)

img = np.fromstring(signedIntsArray, dtype='uint8')

img.shape = (height, width, 4)

srcdc.DeleteDC()
memdc.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwin, hwindc)
win32gui.DeleteObject(bmp.GetHandle())

img_res = cv2.resize(img, (480,270))
return img_res
```